# Daily returns in R and Stata

Tags: r, stata

I do analyze my data ([this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h4z63b72wxas4rl/Sample%20%281%29.csv?dl=0)) to calculate returns but it seems different in results in descriptive stat. First I calculate the return series, then I do regress: return=alpha + residual to save residual. Then I use descriptive stat to check distribution of this residual

My code in R is:

```
#Load data

#Format data
data$Date=as.Date(data$Date,"%m/%d/%Y")
#Returns
log_p=log(data$Close)
ret=100*diff(log(log_p))
library(psych)
describe(ret)
#Regression
reg=lm(ret~1)
summary(reg)
describe(resid(reg))
```

It shows that Kurtosis = 2.85
My code in Stata:

```
gen lprice=log(Close)
gen ret=100*(log(lprice[_n])-log(lprice[_n-1]))
sum ret,detail
reg ret
predict resid, residuals
sum resid, detail
```

It shows that Kurtosis = 5.85

Please explain and if I went wrong, please help me fix it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Off-topic here to ask program-specific questions. But in both R and Stata you are working with differences in the log of the log of closing prices. I don't work with financial data, but I think that's one logarithm too many. The difference in kurtosis is easy to explain. Stata doesn't subtract 3, which many people and programs do because with that a Gaussian has kurtosis 0, but R does. Note that 5.85 - 2.85 = 3.

Comment: @Nick I don't think it's entirely off-topic to ask here about differences between computing platforms, especially if there's some prospect of a statistical explanation for them.  Your comment reads like a fine answer.